Why docRef.snapshots() give an error when called inside an onPressed function?
My code snippet is as follows for an elevated button:
onPressed: () async {
  var docRef = await context
      .read<FirestoreRepository>()
      .firestore
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userData.selfRef.id)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
    'price':
        pricePlans.first.selfRef.id,
    'success_url':
        'https://success.com',
    'cancel_url':
        'https://cancel.com'
  });
  debugPrint(
      'doc added');
  docRef
      .snapshots()
      .listen((ds) {
    if (ds.exists) {
      var url = ds.get('url'); 
      if (context.mounted) {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return CheckoutPage(url: url);
        }));

I am getting an uncaught exception breakpoint at docRef.snapshots(). Why does that happen? What is the fix?
The error is as follows:

Bad state: field "url" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Model file as follows:
class CheckoutSessionModel extends Equatable {
  final String model;
  final String sessionId;
  final String url;
  final String price;
  const CheckoutSessionModel({
    required this.model,
    required this.sessionId,
    required this.url,
    required this.price,
  });

  factory CheckoutSessionModel.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data()!;

    return CheckoutSessionModel(
        model: data['mode'] as String? ?? '',
        sessionId: data['sessionId'] as String? ?? '',
        url: data['url'] as String? ?? '',
        price: data['price'] as String? ?? '');
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [model, sessionId, url, price];
}


What is the error?

It is not giving me any error in the console but app crashes and the breakpoint points to this line in the code.

If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Including a screenshot of a stack trace is not enough. What is the exact exception you get, including the message and stack trace as text?

Bad state: field "url" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

the error you are facing is clearly complaining that the url field does not exist in the snapshot, which you fetched from the firestore. var url = ds.get('url'); this part is probably where the problem comes, what you can do is to print out the data you are fetching and check if there is a url fied that you are trying to pass it to your model's property. like this:
var data = ds.data();
    debugPrint('Document data: $data');

Edit: I recommend using two separate methods for adding your data to your 'checkout_sessions' collection in firebase, and also for reading it.
This way would probably be more efficient and also easier to handle.
try this:
      onPressed: () async {
        await context
            .read<FirestoreRepository>()
            .firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userData.selfRef.id)
            .collection('checkout_sessions')
            .add({
          'price': pricePlans.first.selfRef.id,
          'success_url': 'https://success.com',
          'cancel_url': 'https://cancel.com'
        });
        debugPrint('doc added');

        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(userData.selfRef.id)
              .collection('checkout_sessions')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
              return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
            } else {
              final documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
              final model = documents
                  .where((doc) => !doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites)
                  .map((doc) => CheckoutSessionModel.fromSnapshot(doc))
                  .toList();

              // Assuming you want to use the first model with a valid URL
              final firstModelWithUrl = model.firstWhere(
                (model) => model.url.isNotEmpty,
                orElse: () => CheckoutSessionModel(
                  // try to handle error here
                  model: '',
                  sessionId: '',
                  url: '',
                  price: '',
                ),
              );
              final url = firstModelWithUrl.url;
              return Text('$url');
            }
          },
        );
      },

also I seriously recommend using a state management solution instead of dumping all your logic and methods inside the UI.

The url field is not printed. In reality url field is automatically created and takes a few seconds by the cloud function to create it, after the data has been written to the Firebase Firestore. Thats why I use the listen to snapshots method, but thats not working apparently. Any alternative fix?

@M99Coder in that case your documents have pending write operations by firebase, I will update the answer so you can try it in your code and check the results
